# Return a list without the last element

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

I've just started to learn Racket.

I have this code:

```
#lang racket

(define l1 '(1 2 3 4))
(car l1)
(cdr l1)
```

`(car l1)` returns 1.
`(cdr l1)` returns '(2 3 4)

Is there a function that returns `'(1 2 3)`?

I've tried this:

```
#lang racket

(define l1 '(1 2 3 4))
(map
 (lambda (l i)
   (if (not (= i (sub1 (length l1)))) l '()))
 l1 (range 0 (length l1)))
```

But, it returns: `'(1 2 3 ())`

And I have also tried:

```
#lang racket

(define l1 '(1 2 3 4))
(map
 (lambda (l i)
   (cond ((not (= i (sub1 (length l1)))) l )))
 l1 (range 0 (length l1)))
```

But, it returns: `'(1 2 3 #<void>)`

Comment: Are you allowed to use `reverse`?

Comment: @WillNess Yes, I think so. But I want to make it portable to Scheme (if it is possible).

Comment: try it. :) can you get the *reversed* "butlast" elements with it? (this is what your desired function is known as in common lisp, btw - "butlast").

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this `(filter not empty? (map (lambda (l i) ...`, but it doesn't work. And also, I'm trying to do it with recursion without using `map`.

Comment: but if you're just starting learning Lisp, it is a great exercise to code this up with direct recursion yourself, i.e with just if, null? cons, car, cdr and recursion, to get a feel for it. you should first love writing such small functions yourself, then get tired of writing them yourself, and then switch to using library functions instead.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to do it. I have found the function `filter-not`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189077/discussion-between-will-ness-and-vansfannel).

Comment: This doesn't look like a good use case for map/filter. Also, what should happen if the input list is empty? do we return an empty list or raise an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `map` function always returns a list the same length as its input. You want an output list that is shorter than its input. The function you are looking for is traditionally called `but-last`:

```
(define (but-last xs) (reverse (cdr (reverse xs))))
```

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this ?

```
(define (myCdr l)
    (if (not (pair? (cdr l)))
        '()
        (cons (car l) (myCdr (cdr l)))
    )
)
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. It should now work.
 Thanks Will Ness for the idea :)

Comment: you're welcome. just choose a better name for it. :)

Answer (score 2):

`length` is generally an anti-pattern in Scheme because the entire list needs to be read in order to get the result. W. Ness remarks that `map` does not alter the structure of the list, and the behavior of `filter` is based on the list's *values*, neither of which suit your needs.

Instead of making potentially expensive computations first or awkwardly applying the library functions, you can compute the `init` of a list using direct recursion -

```
(define (init l)
  (cond ((null? l)
         (error 'init "cannot get init of empty list"))
        ((null? (cdr l))
         null)
        (else
         (cons (car l)
               (init (cdr l))))))

(init '(a b c d e)) ;; '(a b c d)
(init '(a))         ;; '(a)
(init '())          ;; init: cannot get init of empty list
```

Or a tail-recursive form that only uses one `reverse` -

```
(define (init l)
  (let loop ((acc null)
             (l l))
    (cond ((null? l)
           (error 'init "cannot get init of empty list"))
          ((null? (cdr l))
           (reverse acc))
          (else
           (loop (cons (car l) acc)
                 (cdr l))))))

(init '(a b c d e)) ;; '(a b c d)
(init '(a))         ;; '(a)
(init '())          ;; init: cannot get init of empty list
```

And lastly a tail-recursive form that does not use `length` *or* `reverse`. For more intuition on how this works, see [*"How do collector functions work in Scheme?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819103/how-do-collector-functions-work-in-scheme) -

```
(define (init l (return identity))
  (cond ((null? l)
         (error 'init "cannot get init of empty list"))
        ((null? (cdr l))
         (return null))
        (else
         (init (cdr l)
               (lambda (r)
                 (return (cons (car l) r)))))))

(init '(a b c d e)) ;; '(a b c d)
(init '(a))         ;; '(a)
(init '())          ;; init: cannot get init of empty list
```

Comment: ... of course filter *can* be used structurally, if we use (x -> [x | p x]) and test for null? in it. still, it's too complicated. :)

Comment: someone wrote ["a Haskell programmer's factorial function"](https://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html), it's hilarious. this one begins to look like a candidate for something like that, too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more, via zipping:

```
#lang racket

(require srfi/1)

(define (but-last-zip xs)
  (if (null xs)
      xs                      ; or error, you choose
      (map (lambda (x y) x)
           xs
           (cdr xs))))
```

Here's another, emulating filtering via lists with appending, where empty lists disappear by themselves:

```
(define (but-last-app xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      xs
      (let ((n (length xs)))
        (apply append                  ; the magic
               (map (lambda (x i)
                      (if (= i (- n 1)) '() (list x)))
                    xs
                    (range n))))))
```

Or we could use the decorate--filter--undecorate directly, it's even more code!

```
(define (but-last-fil xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      xs
      (let ((n (length xs)))
        (map car
             (filter (lambda (x) (not (null? x)))
                     (map (lambda (x i)
                            (if (= i (- n 1)) '() (list x)))
                          xs
                          (range n)))))))
```

Comment: `but-last-zip` is beautiful: I had the idea of using `map` with one of its arguments a list one shorter and then, stupidly, got stuck on making such a list cheaply (like I said, stupidly).  Annoyingly, it doesn't work in Racket because of Annoying Racket Fussiness, but `for/list` does: at least it should be consistently fussy.

Comment: it works, with the `(require srfi/1)`. If you have a Rackety version, with the for/list etc., it would be a nice addition to this unexpectedly sprawling entry. :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another alternative, assuming that the list is non-empty. It's efficient (it performs a single pass over the list), and it doesn't get any simpler than this!

```
(define (delete-last lst)
  (drop-right lst 1))

(delete-last '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(1 2 3)
```

Comment: if only `take` allowed for negative numbers... (Haskell does, khm, khm...)

Comment: @WillNess Aha! but in Racket we have `drop-right`. I had forgotten about it!

Comment: have you tried it on an empty list?.... ukhm, nice save, requiring it to be non-empty. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an equivalent of [Will Ness's beautiful `but-last-zip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54888731/5920214) which does not rely on `srfi/1` in Racket: without `srfi/1` Racket's `map` insists that all its arguments are the same length (as does the [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/) version in fact) but it is common in other Lisps to have the function terminate at the end of the shortest list.

This function uses Racket's `for/list` and also wires in the assumption that the result for the empty list is the empty list.

```
#lang racket

(define (but-last-zip xs)
  (for/list ([x xs] [y (if (null? xs) xs (rest xs))])
    x))
```

I think Will's version is purer: mapping functions over things is a very Lisp thing to do I think, while `for/list` feels less Lispy to me.  This version's only advantage is that it does not require a module.

Comment: it *is* more Racket-y. `for` constructs are decidedly Racket-y, that was my impression.

Comment: Yes, I agree: I think in some sense 'more Rackety' is 'less Lispy'.  Neither is necessarily better of course.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution using recursion:

```
#lang racket

(define but-last
  (lambda (l)
    (cond ((null? (cdr l)) '())
          (else (cons (car l) (but-last (cdr l)))))))
```

And another solution using `filter-not` and `map`:

```
#lang racket

(define l1 '(1 2 3 4))

(filter-not empty? (map
 (lambda (l i)
   (if (not (= i (sub1 (length l1)))) l empty))
 l1 (range 0 (length l1))))
```

Comment: Just be aware that your `but-last` function is not a total function: it will throw an error if applied to an empty list. The second solution behaves differently: it will return an empty list if applied to an empty list.

Comment: ok, this *is* structural. although, much too complicated. :) -- oh,  no, I take it back. what's the result for `'(1 () 2)`??

Comment: btw, what's the last one's complexity? can you tell, is it linear?

Comment: calling `length` inside a loop, I didn't even see that waaaaa :(

Comment: Please, instead of criticise, please show me how to fix all of those errors you comment.

Comment: of course. the "criticism" wasn't that at all. it was intended to give you some hints, to provoke discussion.

Comment: Calling length inside a loop. If I'm doing it this way is because I don't know any other way to do it. With the comment "waaaaaaa :(" I can not imagine what the user is suggesting me. This comment is very constructive.

Comment: people sometimes react for themselves, not for the audience. I'm sure it was just a surprise at not seeing it right away, not directed at you, least of all to cause you any ill feelings. repeated length in a loop is such an anti-pattern. it leads to quadratic behavior, because it is calculated each time anew, and needs traversing the list to its end each time anew. Instead we should save the value, using `let` -- see it used in my answer. :)

Comment: another issue is that for `(define l1 '(1 () 3 4))`, the result should be `'(1 () 3)`, but instead, with the second version, it is `'(1 3)`. compare how you are using filter, with how it is used in my answer. if you have more questions, don't hesitate to ask here. :)